# Baking Key Frame Animation in Blender

Tags: animation, blender

I have a rigged model using an armiture in blender, I was wonder how you could bake the animation as kayframed data so that I could remove the armiture and the model still walks without being rigged.

Comment: Googling turned up this: http://www.rulflinks.blogspot.com/ Maybe this helps.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what exactly you are asking. I mean, Blender's wiki has a page called "Animation Baking" but I can't tell if that's relevant to your question because I can't tell what exactly you're asking http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.4/Source/Animation/AnimationBaking

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat manual process but works without any plugins in 2.5 and later. For each keyframe you want to 'bake' you need to insert a VisualLocation, VisualRotation or VisualLocRot keyframe in the target armature. After this you can unparent your control rig and the target still moves as it used to.